# Jenkins Weblogic Deployment Plugin Failed When pointed to slave

Tags: jenkins, weblogic, weblogic12c, jenkins-agent

Jenkins Weblogic deployment was failed when pointed to Slave with below error.

```
    [WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - Retrieving artifacts recorded [filtered resources on (.*)VODSHM(.*)\.war]...
[WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - the base directory specified [/opt/jenkins/workspace/vospcore_vod-shm_daily_deployments/shm-vod-service/target] is invalid (doesn't exists or is not a directory or has insufficient privilege). Please check the job configuration
java.lang.RuntimeException: The base directory specified [/opt/jenkins/workspace/vospcore_vod-shm_daily_deployments/shm-vod-service/target] is invalid (doesn't exists or is not a directory or has insufficient privilege)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.deploy.weblogic.FreeStyleJobArtifactSelectorImpl.selectArtifactRecorded(FreeStyleJobArtifactSelectorImpl.java:61)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.deploy.weblogic.task.DeploymentTaskServiceImpl.perform(DeploymentTaskServiceImpl.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.deploy.weblogic.WeblogicDeploymentPlugin.perform(WeblogicDeploymentPlugin.java:236)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
ERROR: [WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - Failed to get artifact from archive directory : The base directory specified [/opt/jenkins/workspace/vospcore_vod-shm_daily_deployments/shm-vod-service/target] is invalid (doesn't exists or is not a directory or has insufficient privilege)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] DEPLOYMENT FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Configuration is as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE01n.jpg)

Please let us know what is the solution for this pro

Comment: "insufficient privilege" is the first to check.